# React, DotNet Core Localization

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, localization

I've been searching for an example of how to do *Localization* and *Internationalization* with ASP.NET Core and React.

For now, I have managed to set up my resource files in a new class library in my Core project and can get a single resource by string using the `IStringLocalizer`.

This is my Controller:

```csharp
[HttpGet]
[Route("v1/get-resources")]
public IActionResult GetResources()
{
    var resources = _sharedLocalizer.GetResources();

    return Ok(resources);
}
```

The `GetResource` method looks like this:

```csharp
public IEnumerable<string> GetResources()
{
    return _localizer["Hello"];
}
```

All of this is working fine and I am getting translations.

My question now is, how to use this in my React App?

Comment: Hello, can you share if you found a solution?